# Can this kind of lighting take good photos of perfume products with some effects

Tags: equipment-recommendation, product-photography, light

I want to buy lighting to take pictures of perfume and glass products in general,
But there is an effect that I like like the pictures below and I want to take something similar.
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
I found this product on Alibaba website,
https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/2-Packs-Photographic-Lighting-Youtuber-set_1600338579919.html
But I wonder if this type of lighting is Enough for taking good pictures of perfumes, and is it possible to make effects such as the reflection of glass on the background as picture above.
Would you recommend it or this light is better?
https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1446716-REG/neewer_10085939_700w_photography_softbox_lighting.html?gclid=CjwKCAiAz--OBhBIEiwAG1rIOs2f1ijw67lunAs02nox2NwoorHYz2mfF1jPq2zitmhhczry5A7RHRoCudgQAvD_BwE
..

Thank you in advance

Comment: Those two shots look like they used a focused light source that's a little bit out of focus to give the soft lighting edges. If you have a flashlight (also called a torch) that has focusing capability (e.g., a Maglight), experiment with that.

Comment: I don't have a Maglight and I don't have any kind of lighting, that's why I want your advice Is the light which i put the link above suitable for taking pictures of perfumes, and which is better the product in the first link or in the second link.. Thanks

Comment: I'd lay odds they were shot with polarised light, & a fair chance they're composited, especially the 2nd one. There's far too little shine/specularity on the front surfaces imo to have got that with regular lighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need a focused light source or a light source with a snoot. The two links you posted, a panel with barn doors and a softbox, are too broad for the desired effect.

I did a quickie setup with a [focused flashlight](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01J8B219O) and a focused flashlight with a snoot. The left image is a focusable flashlight with a fairly sharp beam with a diamond pattern (due to the large square LED array), and suffers chromatic aberration due to the poor optics used in the flashlight. The right image uses the same focused flashlight with a circular aperture snoot. The lighting implements are shown below the respective image. The snoot was rolled from a page out of a magazine.
 By playing with lighting angles, snoot opening diameter, snoot length, and distance from the light to subject, you can get different lighting effects. Cost is under 20 USD. There are commercial lighting setups with snoots.

[image: Tequila bottle]

Comment: This is really amazing, Thank you very much for this valuable explanation,
Excuse me, I have an additional question. Do you recommend the lighting links that I put above to photograph perfume products in case I want them without effect? I only want normal photos with beautiful lighting and shadows, Which do you recommend first or second? Thank you again

Comment: Softboxes give a nice diffuse light which gives soft shadows. This sort of lighting can be done with *windowing lighting* which you should try to see if you like the effect.  I don't have experience with panel lights. You should also look in to light tents. You can build one from a [gallon milk jug](https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/photo/essays/vanRiper/020809.htm) and one or two shop lights, or, purchase a *light tent*.